# What is the intuition behind the multiplication defined for Octonions?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

I had been working with Complex Numbers and Quaternions and their Matrix Representation. Till now everything had been quite logical and it's easy to follow the extension from complex numbers to Quaternions.
Now I have moved on to Octonions and the way Octonions Multiplication is defined itself doesn't seem to follow a pattern; it looks highly unintuitive to me.
Can anyone explain why the Multiplication in Octonions is defined the way it is defined?
Or is it that there is not pattern to understand and it is just that this definition works out for it to have a Structure like Division Algebra?

Comment: There is a uniform way to construct each of the successive division algebras, $\Bbb R, \Bbb C, \Bbb H, \Bbb O$ from the previous one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction

Comment: What made quaternion multiplication intuitive? Why is octonion multiplication not intuitive in the same way?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern what i meant by Octonions Multiplication as not as intuitive as Quarternions multiplication was that  in Quaternions multiplication there is a logical pattern evident as there is a cycle flowing between i,j and k that is  ij=k,jk=i,ki=j ijk=1 and ji=-i and so on i am not able to find any such logical pattern in Octonions multiplication please tell me the right way of approaching and understanding Octonions multiplication.